# ¿Como puedo usar $_SESSION?

Tags: php

tengo este error "Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\html\index2.php on line 9"

```
<?php
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $impr = $_SESSION['user'] = "$user";

    //conectar a la base de datos
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    if ($filas > 0) {
        header("location:index2.php");
    } else {
        echo "NO SE A ENCONTRADO NINGUN DATO";
        echo "POR FAVOR VERIFICA TUS DATOS";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Al margen del problema que planteas, para mantener los datos de sesión en cada fichero, lo primero de todo que debes hacer nada más abrir las llaves es un session_start(). Osea:

```
<?php
session_start();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

En el `<form>` del HTML, asegúrate de que el `action` es correcto y también de que el `method` es `POST`.